# android custom layout that is not rectangular

Tags: android, android-layout

I am making an android app. here I want to make a view that is something like the image. here top layout will consist of some view items and bottom layout will have some other view item. Not sure how to achieve this. would be helpful if any tutorial or link for making custom layout like this.
thanks in advance.

Layout to achieve:

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1):

Every single layout is rectangular, so technically you cannot do that. To make a layout look like this you can:

**Make it with a background**
Just draw that layout in your favourite bitmap editor and set it as background. It's probably the easiest and most performant solution.

**Mask your layout with a path**
This approach is way more complex, but allows cutting layouts and its children freely.

Basically you need a layout with draw method overriden, a mask and a simple operation on layers:

```
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas) {
     PorterDuffXfermode pdMode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

     int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);

     super.draw(canvas);

     paint.setXfermode(pdMode);
     canvas.drawPath(mask, paint);

     canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
     paint.setXfermode(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `slope line` image and then in `RelativeLayout` or `LinearLayout` place dark green color layout, then slope line image and line green layout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: can u explain a bit more ?

Comment: That won't create exactly what OP is asking for. A slope line used by Relative or Linear Layout will have some empty space.

Comment: Colleague of mine achieved sort of bow behavior sort of U image in the midway of two layouts. It will work fine. Get the image slope line image, this slope line is layered with first layer dark green color then blue line and then third layer light green color. Now this layered image will work for you.